# Spring boot, can't get a list of Objects which this object is related to another object (@OneToOne)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, http

I'm new working with Spring boot, I'm having trouble in getting a list of objects which this objects is related to another object. To make a better explanion I'll show the adding request, which is working fine:

Sorry for the language my college teacher suggested to use portuguese language, the main thing is a software where there are customers and inside of this object there is an address. OneToOne related

```
{
"nome":"Adriano",
"complemento":"DevOps",
"numero": 123,
"endereco": {
    "cep":88787123,
    "logradouro": "Rua petuinha",
    "uf": "SC",
    "bairro": "Dourado",
    "cidade": "PH"
}
```

Fortunately, both records for customer and address were inserted into database with the correct relationship between them.

The main problem is in the `getAll` customer Endpoint, which only occurs error when there is at least one Customer with not null address inside it, this the customer has a null address the problem do not happen:

Check add and getAll customer Endpoints

[image: endpoints image]

Probably the error occurs in the getAll endopoint, I'm returning a list of objects, and when I do the request for this endpoint this message happen:

```
2021-12-01 09:49:02.209[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m1632[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: br.unisul.trabalho.springboot.modelo.Cliente["endereco"]->br.unisul.trabalho.springboot.modelo.Endereco$HibernateProxy$JFhZvNZK["hibernateLazyInitializer"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: br.unisul.trabalho.springboot.modelo.Cliente["endereco"]->br.unisul.trabalho.springboot.modelo.Endereco$HibernateProxy$JFhZvNZK["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.serialize(ReferenceTypeSerializer.java:386) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

To this post not be so big, I'm sharing my repository with all files:

https://github.com/adrielkirch/crud-springboot-clientes

Graciously from Brazil

Comment: 1. finding (in your pom): mysql or mariadb??? ;) (please decide) 2. (in your pom): why do you overwrite (the spring-boot managed) hibernate dependencies?? ...

Comment: xerx593, bin deleted I don't why there was that directory ( =

Comment: You've accepted an answer to your question. For this reason, the system recognises this question is answered without needing the word "Solved" in the tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this issue adding this to de model class:

```
@Entity 
@Table (name = "cliente")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class Cliente implements Serializable{...
```

And adding this to the **application.properties**

```
*spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false*
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same model for getting data from API as well as storing it in DB which is not good practice. It is always better to segregate API and DB models.

However, you can perhaps fix your issue by adding following annotation on your class:

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Cliente implements Serializable {...
```

Comment: Sukhmeet Sethi, thanks for the help but it still throwing a error 500

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace for the error?

Comment: Updated the post with full trace (=

Comment: For the error you shared : try adding following in your application.properties:
`spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false`